# How to remove rounded black corners which appeared after system upgrade?

Tags: screen, android-10

I recently let my Nokia 3.1 to upgrade to Android 10.
I don't know if it's Nokia's will or Google's but rounded black corners appeared on my screen, and are kept permanently visible during any app runtime.
Is there a way to remove this feature ? I have found nothing in the system configuration menus. I also tried some app implementing custom corners but apart to add another layer of corners, it can't remove the ones I initially want to disappear.

Some pictures:

[image: Rounded corners 1]
[image: Rounded corners 2]

The rounded corners don't appear in screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this on reddit (thanks to "jyapayne"):

```
adb shell settings put secure sysui_rounded_size 1
adb shell settings put secure sysui_rounded_content_padding 5
```

First line is the corner "roundness" and second line ist the padding of the status-bar elements to the edge.

[The Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/9pko21/)

Comment: [link](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=78645950&postcount=14) The sysui_rounded_size 1 removes almost completely the corners. The value 0 removes the bottom corners, top ones are unaffected. Negative values, "null", don't nothing. "default" value or deleting the key bring back the default corners. [The source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/ScreenDecorations.java) (I suppose it is) doesn't mention any other available key to turn the corners off completely.